# Jenkins triggering job twice

Tags: jenkins, cron

I have a job that is configured to schedule and run a job periodically using the following schedule:

```
01 14 *  * 1-5
```

For some reason, the job is triggering twice every day at the same time. I cannot work out why it is triggering twice. I suspect two possible issues:

1. The Day of Month (DOM) and Day of Week (DOW) is contradicting
2. The fact that there are multiple spaces after each column might be confusing Jenkins

**Questions**

- Am i correct that the above says the job should run daily at 14:01 UTC?
- What is the significance of the last field? If the fourth field (day of month) specifies * meaning every day of the month, what would be the purpose of the last field (Day of Week)?
- What would be the behaviour if i had something like this (where DOM and DOW contradict)

  ```
       01 14 *  * 5
  ```

Comment: There is an extensive help manual built right in to Jenkins, all you have to do is click on the question mark next to the scheduling input box. It also shows how to set a time zone if desired. The 1-5 you have in the last field means weekdays, I don't see anything wrong with your syntax, but if you set it and click outside of the box, Jenkins will tell you if there's a syntax error. It will also tell you the last time it would have run, and the next time it would run.

Comment: I read that manual several times. It does not answer most of the specific questions I asked. As an example the behaviour when DOW and DOM both clash.

Comment: I don't think that they clash at all. By specifying * for the DOM, you're basically saying the job is eligible to run any day of the month unless otherwise restricted, which is what the DOW does. So in the case of "01 14 *  * 5", it would run on every Friday of every month @ 14:01 in your timezone.